# Silverlight web application. GPU acceleration

Tags: silverlight, web, gpu

In the sivlierlight web application html page layout defined param, that enable GPU:

Is it possible to check hardware usage of GPU from Silverlight web application?

Comment: What do you mean by hardware usage? Whether GPU rendering is successfully enabled, or how much of the GPU is being used? Do you need to do this programmatically?

Comment: Александр, спасибо за ответ! Думаю на русском будет проще. Постараюсь описать подробнее. Вопрос в том, что наше приложение должно работать на допотопных машинах со встроенной хиленькой видеокартой. Вот и встал вопрос определения средней температуры по больнице: на каких машинах GPU поддерживается, а на каких-нет. Возможно ли это сделать средствами Silverlight? Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: here is translation to English:Alexander, thank you for your reply!  I will try to describe in more detail. The issue is that our application should run on machines with built-antediluvian puny card. That was a question of determining the average temperature in the hospital: which machines GPU supported, and on what does not. Is it possible to do this by means of Silverlight? Thanks in advance for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Good thing you gave me the russian version. The english is indecipherable. Your question is an interesting one. I can't say for sure, but I believe there is no way to directly detect (using code) whether GPU acceleration is successfully enabled. (You can turn on debug overlays, and you can use COM or P/Invoke in trusted mode to query the GPU, but both are not suitable for you.)

You may be able to create some sort of benchmark. You can't get the frames-per-second programatically either, but there might be some trick to try to measure it. Eg, start an animation of the position of a control, and count how many times LayoutUpdated is fired per second.

Anyway, you should know that GPU acceleration doesn't do much in Silverlight. It is helpful only in a few situations, such as 2D games with lots of sprites. In all other cases, Silverlight is rendered by the CPU (with pretty good performance).